# Using Sparse Tensors for a Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, sparse-matrix, large-data

I am doing a project that involves multiple patients arranged as 1D arrays of approximately 3 billion values, however only 1 million of these values are non-zero, which is why I want to use sparse tensors with Pytorch and spconv. However, an issue arises when I input the size of the sparse tensors, since the largest indices in my array is 3 billion, the size of my sparse tensors remains 3 billion. Therefore, when I try to input the dimensions in my first neural network layer, I get a memory error as it is impossible to create the appropriate gradients that have a shape of 3 billion. I think my reasoning is incorrect and I have not much experience with sparse tensors and how to input them into a neural network without turning them back into dense tensors. Any help is appreciated. I can send some of the code if needed.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.net = spconv.SparseSequential(
            
            spconv.SubMConv1d(1, 32, 3, 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            spconv.SubMConv1d(32, 64, 3, 1),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 26, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)

    def forward(self, x):
        # x: SparseConvTensor with batch_size=1
        x=spconv.SparseConvTensor.from_dense(x.unsqueeze(0))
        output = self.net(x)
        output = self.dropout1(output)
        output = self.fc1(output)
        output = F.relu(output)
        output = self.dropout2(output)
        output = self.fc2(output)
        output = F.log_softmax(output, dim=1)
        return output
```

This is my model or at least a prototype. The input looks a little like this:

```
SparseConvTensor[shape=torch.Size([1, 3088358329])].
```

But the model and the data don't fit, however, if I change a dimension in spconv.SubMConv1d with the 3 billion, I get memory problems. Keep in mind, I have 32Gb of RAM.